# Use stack to check for any unbalanced paranthesis on user input in Python

Tags: python, parentheses

Am required to use a stack to check for any unbalanced parenthesis on user input. The logic of the code should use the stack `push` method to add an opening bracket to the stack and pop it out whenever a closing bracket is encountered. When the opening and closing brackets aren't balanced the code should break and print `parenthesis unbalanced`.
I tried to cheat with this code but the last test case busted me

```
mytext="))((("#this string input is just sample, the real input is captured from user
if(mytext.count(")")!=mytext.count("(")):
    print("The paranthesis are not balanced")
else:
    print("The parenthesis are balanced")
```

So decided to go the hard way to build a stack class with its methods, am stuck at capturing the opening bracket `"("` and adding it t the stack and then scanning input for a closing bracket `")"` and then call pop to remove the opening bracket from the stack. I feel like the stack should be empty for code to output balanced parenthesis and unempty for output unbalanced parenthesis. The code is below

```
##First you need to create a stack class
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)
    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()#removes last element added
    def print_stack(self):#print function for debugging
        print(self.items)







def balanced(expression):#This function checks whether input from user has balanced parenthesis
    #create a stack object
     mystack=Stack()
    #scan user input for opening bracket and add to stack
    #I need help from this point onwards
    if "(" in expression:#if opening bracket exists in input, i feel like i should iterate through the expression
       mystack.push(0,"(")
    if ")" in expression:#remove the previously added opening bracket
       mystack.pop(0):
     ##implement empty_check and return accordingly
        
print(balanced(input()))
```

I also feel like i should just use a list to scan for `"("` from the string add them to the list, scan for the opposite syntax `")"` and do some comparisons on their lengths.

Comment: No, just scan the string from left to right and push/pop once you encounter a (  )

Comment: Can you post code on how to do that?, please :))

Comment: Well your idea is good. You just need to do those checks in a loop on each character instead of checking `in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```
def check_paranthesis(data):
    stack = []
    pairs = {
        '}': '{',
        ']': '[',
        ')': '('
    }
    for i in data:
        if i in ('(', '[', '{'):
            stack.append(i)
        elif not stack or pairs[i] != stack.pop():
            return False
    
if stack:
        return False
return True


print(check_paranthesis('[()]'))    # True
print(check_paranthesis('[({})]')) # True
print(check_paranthesis('[(})}]'))  # False
print(check_paranthesis('[(])'))  # False
print(check_paranthesis('[()'))  # False
print(check_paranthesis('[(]'))  # False
print(check_paranthesis(']['))  # False
print(check_paranthesis('[['))  # False
```

The idea is very simple, keep on pushing the left counterparts to stack and as soon you encounter the right counterpart in the expression, pop the stack and see if it is the corresponding right counterpart for that bracket/curly/parentheses.

At the end if your stack is empty it means your expression was balanced.

Comment: Can you modify to just check for these types of brackets `"("`

Comment: Do you mean a single opening parentheses, if yes then It works for this as well `print(check_paranthesis('(')).   # False`.

Comment: What about this `)))))('

Comment: You need an underflow check before `stack.pop()` (and don't need the first if).

Answer (score 0):

```
mytext="))((("#this string input is just sample, the real input is captured from user
if(mytext.count(")")!=mytext.count("(")):
    print("The paranthesis are not balanced")
else:
    print("The parenthesis are balanced")
```

One of the reason it failed was, it's not checking - `)` shouldn't come before `(`.

One simple approach you can use is, create a counter variable with initial value as 0. Now iterate over the user string and on each `(` do `counter++` & on each `)` do `counter--`.

Break if at any iteration `counter < 0`.

now outside loop, if `counter==0`, its valid else invalid.

---

Sample code:

```
mytext="((()()))"

ctr = 0
for c in mytext:
    if c == ')':
        ctr -= 1
    elif c == '(':
        ctr += 1
    print("c={}, ctr={}".format(c,ctr))
    if ctr < 0:
        break
if ctr == 0:
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Not valid")
```

Comment: The code passed 7 test cases, failed the last test case, which was the eighth, let me apply the changes you suggested

Comment: It would be easier if you just posted your code and advice on your answer

Comment: @Source_Code_001 sure, didnt have a proper system access earlier.